# GET method in php mvc framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I am writing a PHP MVC framework from scratch by myself, I use this `.htaccess` rules to redirect all requests to my bootstrap:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php?url=$1 [PT,L
```

Now the problem is I can't use GET method anymore on forms, when I want to submit a search form using GET method the get parameter won't send, but it will work with post but it's not right for a search form.

Comment: i the bootstrap.php is in root directory?

Comment: Try `[QSA,PT,L]`, and if you can post a sample of how your forms or URLs look like when using GET, it would help.

Comment: its  in WWW folder,i use a similar htaccess to redirect all request from index.php tha is in the root to the bootstrap in the WWW folder

Comment: @Prix: thanks,the command did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the .htaccess I am using for my own MVC , may be you can try this

eg usage :localhost/your_webroot/controller/action/?get_parameters=anything

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ your_webroot/index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
# This denies all web access to your .ini file. 
<files config.base.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
<files errorlogs.log>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me. Just add this into your .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So you can use this URL.

```
http://localhost:81/mywebsite/public/search?query=ironman
```

and this too.

```
http://localhost:81/mywebsite/public/search/ironman
```